# Stereo speech into a file

Tags: objective-c, file, file-io

In the recorder application,I'm trying to capture the stereo speech data into a file.

```
for ( int i=0; i<bufferList->mNumberBuffers; i++ ) {
    memcpy(bufferList->mBuffers[i].mData, audio->mBuffers[i].mData, byteCount);
}
```

The above code contains the recorded speech data. The file writing goes as below.

```
NSString *root  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [root stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mic_in.raw"];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [[NSData data] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];        
}
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:audio->mBuffers[0].mData length:byteCount];
NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
[handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
[handle writeData:myData];

myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:audio->mBuffers[1].mData length:byteCount];
[handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
[handle writeData:myData];

[handle closeFile];
```

The 'stereo' speech is recorded in 'non interleaved' format.

The saved file contents are not proper. (For e.g. for 15 seconds of speech data, only 2.5 is saved. Saved data also not proper)
The file writing for 'Mono' speech is working fine.

I'm not sure, what is wrong in the 'stereo' speech file writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue of stereo file writing got it resolved, as follows.

The very frequent file operations at callback was causing the data loss. 
So, in callback, the data (after interleaving conversion) is saved in a big buffer and at the end of speech recording, the complete buffer content is written into a file at one shot.

The above approach, resolved the stereo file capturing issue.